# Comma operator in return

Tags: javascript, comma-operator

I was reading the JS from one page and this is what I found (the source is deobfuscated by google chrome dev tools):

```
var db = function(a) {
    return a.replace(/[^\w\s\.\|`]/g, 
    function(b) {
        return "\\" + b
    })
};
```

Is there a some trick with the first comma operator operand (the `a.replace()` one)?

From my point of view the ``` a.replace(/[^\w\s\.\|``]/g, ``` part is completely redundant and can be removed.

Have I missed something?

Comment: It's the callback from `replace`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), but a simple [arguments list](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.4) of the call to `.replace` - notice the parenthesis.

Your deobfuscator better should've indented it like this:

```
return a.replace(/[^\w\s\.\|`]/g, function(b) {
    return "\\" + b;
});
```

Btw, that function could be replaced by the simple string `"\\$&"`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no comma operator.

See the documentation for [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
newstring = str.replace(regexp, function);
```

The poor formatting makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

It's basically doing

```
a.replace(/([^\w\s\.\|`])/g, "\\$1");
```